# Condition for a Lagrangian submanifold to be totally geodesic

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Consider $(M,\omega)$ a symplectic manifold and $L\subset M$ a Lagrangian submanifold. Let $J$ be an almost complex structure and $g:=\omega(.,J.)$ a compatible riemannian metric .

Are there conditions that we can put on the lagrangian submanifold $L$ so that this becomes totally geodesic ?

I know that given a totally real submanifold of an almost complex manifold one can always find a metric for which he is totally geodesic, but I was wondering if with the existence of the symplectic form $\omega$ something more could be said.

Any insight is appreciated, thanks in advance.